# invalid json data format

Tags: javascript, json

What is wrong with the following json data format?

```
{
    success: true,
    total: 100,
    data: [
        {
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "22"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following error on JSONLint:

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    success: true,    t
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

It says the error is on line one, but on line 1 I only have the opening curly brace. Any help please. Thank you

Comment: This line is missing an ending quote: `"id": "22`

Comment: I added the missing quote, same problem

Comment: You could also use following [website](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) to check for validation errors. It will tell you in a more readable language what you did wrong.

Comment: *"It says the error is on line one"* Do you see where the arrow points to? It points to `success`, and the message is `Expecting 'STRING'`. Quite clear IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON should have all keys quoted. You're also missing a close quote.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "total": 100,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "22"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing quotes after 22 and rest of the key should also have the quotes to make it valid JSON.

```
{
  "id": "22"
}
```

Try this

```
{
    "success": true,
    "total": 100,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "22
        }
    ]
}
```